# cacert file not found on ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, certificate, ssl-certificate, coldfusion-9

For my ColdFusion 8 server, I can see the cacerts file in the 
following path: `C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\jre\bin`

However, the cacert file is not present on my ColdFusion 9 server at the same location.

I am trying to install a cert into the ColdFusion truststore by following the 
following steps:

```
1)      Run the command prompt as administrator on the ColdFusion server

2)      Make a backup of the original cacerts file in case you run into issues

3)    Change the directory to your truststore’s location (where cacerts file is located).

        In our case: C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\jre\bin

4)    Type this command (use current JVM and use current JVM’s keytool):

       C:\ColdFusion8\runtime\jre\bin>keytool -import -v -alias exported -file C:\ColdF

       usion8\runtime\jre\lib\security\exported.cer -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit

 5)    Type yes at the prompt to “Trust this certificate?”

 6)   Restart the ColdFusion service It will not read the updated cacerts file until you do this.
```

Is there something new for ColdFusion 9? I have successfully installed the certificate for ColdFusion 8 following the above steps? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

The default truststore is the JRE's cacerts file. This file is typically located in the following places:

- **Server Configuration:**

  cf_root/runtime/jre/lib/security/cacerts
- **Multiserver/J2EE on JRun 4 Configuration:**

  jrun_root/jre/lib/security/cacerts
- **Sun JDK installation:**

  jdk_root/jre/lib/security/cacerts

You can verify the JRE that ColdFusion is using from the administrator under the 'System Information' page. Look for the Java Home line.

Comment: I would use CertMan to make your life easier. Nice free cf admin extension http://certman.riaforge.org